# How to keep segmented control in the settings bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, application-settings

Hi can  any one can help me how to keep segmented control in the settings bundle in iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007071), segmented controls are not supported in the settings bundle.